# Unzip file from Rstudio project return an error

Tags: r

I saved a zip file of a dataset into Rstudio project. I am trying to unzip the file. I got the zip file from [this](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset.php?cod=183). Then, I saved it in my Rstudio project.
I tried this code:

```
filetemp <- "appendicitis.zip" ## just assign a name to a zip.file
appendDat <- read.table(unz( filetemp,"appendicitis.zip"))  ## to unzip and read the data.
```

I got this error"

```
    Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot locate file 'appendicitis.zip' in zip file 'appendicitis.zip'
Called from: open.connection(file, "rt")
```

any help please?

Comment: How many files are there in zip file? Please make sure there is no sub-folder under zip file.

Comment: There is no sub-folder it is just one file of data

Comment: Swap the two arguments: `read.table(unz("appendicitis.zip", filetoextract))`. (The man page uses `description` to be the zip file, and `filename` to be the file you want extracted ... perhaps a little confusing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems not using correct file from `appendicitis.zip` is the problem.

```
appendDat <- read.table(unz( filetemp,"appendicitis.zip"))
```

Please change the `appendicitis.zip` name to actual name of the file under the zip. Suppose the actual file in `appendicitis.zip` is `abc.dat`. Then above line should be

```
appendDat <- read.table(unz( filetemp,"abc.dat"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I named it as it. I did not change the name of the file. here is the `url` of the zip file http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/dataset.php?cod=183

Comment: Pls unzip that file and check for actual file contained in it. You should use the actual file name. Other option is not to 'unz' function. Read.Table can read from zip file.